# How to install extension in webkit remote devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, electron, remote-debugging

I am developing Electron application

When in electron , I create two WebView ,I want to show DevTools in one WebView to debug another WebView.

I use `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-debugging-port', '9221');` , but I can't install extension in DevTools that is opened by  -

`http://127.0.0.1:9221/devtools/inspector.html?${current.replace('ws://', 'ws=')}`

How can I do ?